# Proof of Konig-Egervary theorem using Dilworth's theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, extremal-combinatorics

I am doing a discrete mathematics course as a graduate student.Our instructor first proved Dilworth's theorem which states that:

> **Th.** Let $P$ be a finite poset. Then the maximum size of an antichain in $P$ is equal to the minimum number of disjoint chains required to cover $P$.

Now he gave a theorem known as *Konig-Egervary theorem* as an exercise.The statement is as follows:

> **Th.** Let $A$ be a $(0,1)$-matrix.Then the minimum number of lines required to cover all $1$'s in $A$ is equal to the maximum number of $1$'s in $A$ no two of which are on a line.

By line,we mean row or column.Now he told us that we have to use Dilworth's theorem by taking a suitable poset.He also gave us a hint.The hint is as follows:

> $x_{ij}=1\iff (i,j)\in P$ and $P$ is equipped with $\leq$ such that $(i_1,j_1)\leq (i_2,j_2)\iff i_1=i_2$ and $j_1\leq j_2$ or $j_1=j_2$ and $i_1\leq i_2$.

But, unfortunately I found that this relation is not transitive on $P$ beccause $(1,1)\leq (1,2)\leq (2,2)$ but $(1,1)\not\leq (2,2)$ if the $(0,1)$-matrix is $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$.So this hint seems to be of no use.So,what should be the suitable poset $P$ on which we have to apply Dilworth's theorem?

Comment: There seems to be an error in the hint: "$i_1-i_2$".

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Sorry for the typo.

Comment: If you can find the book by Reichmeider, The Equivalence of Some Combinatorial Matching Theorems, it will solve all your problems.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I got the book.

Comment: Good! I hope you get a lot out of it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please do me one more favour,since I do not have enough time to spend over combinatorics(As it is one of the four modules we have to study),can you tell me the exact location in the book where I can get my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the book myself, but there's a chapter on Dilworth's Theorem, and isn't there a chapter on Konig's Theorem? That's where I'd look, if I had the book in front of me.

Comment: Making any progress, Kishalay?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I am trying to understand the whole thing,once I get that,I will post it.